# python ctypes how to map int**

Tags: python, ctypes

There is c struct definition

```
struct Matrix {
    int width;
    int height;
    int** data;
};
```

How to use python's ctypes.Struct to define it?

```
class Matrix( ctypes.Structure ):
    _fields_ = [
        ( "width", ctypes.c_int ),
        ( "height", ctypes.c_int ),
        ( "data", ??? ),
    ]
```

I don't know how to define the "data" 's type.
Anyone here help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most literal translation of `int**` would be:

```
ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
```

That is, it is a pointer to a pointer to an int.

A potentially more idiomatic way is a 2D array:

```
ctypes.c_int * width * height
```

, but to do that you need to know how many elements are *in* the array - the size is part of the type in ctypes. If, as it seems, you don't know that size in advance (and it can change per instance of the struct), a pointer to a pointer is the best option.

To instantiate this takes a little less indirection - by the time you want to create the array, by definition you *will* know how big it needs to be. So, you can just do:

```
m.data = (ctypes.c_int * width * height)()
```

Which will give you a `height`-length array of `width`-length arrays of `c_int`. That is, it does (broadly) the same thing as the C++ code:

```
m.data = new int[width][height];
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
m.data = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int) * width * height)
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to create an instance of type ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
?

Comment: @dowebpress.com: the same way you create instances of any type in Python: `type_name()`.

Comment: @dowebpress.com the most direct answer to that is `ctypes.pointer(ctypes.pointer(5))` creates a pointer to a pointer to the number 5 and is of type `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))`. But for a useful answer to what you probably actually want to do (create a 2D array), see my updated answer.